# Increase space between numerations and info in bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, horizontal

I'm currently learning about LaTeX. Regarding the bibliography I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. I tried `biblatex` and it worked, but I would have had to modify a lot, because all of the styles don't fit the required layout of the bibliography.

So I decided not to use an extra package and use `thebibliography` that comes with LaTeX. It works fine so far. For the documentclass KOMA-Script is being used.

Edit (Full example):

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
oneside,
listof=totoc,
pagesize,
parskip,
captions=tableheading,          
listof=nochaptergap,    
%%fleqn,
numbers=noendperiod,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage
[
    a4paper,
    centering,
    left=3cm, 
    right=3cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    headsep=1cm,
    %footskip=2.5cm,
]{geometry}


%%Standard
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%Zeilenabstand 1.5 wie bei Word
\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MSonehalfspacing}{%
  \setstretch{1.44}%  default
  \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {1.448}%
  \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {1.399}%
  \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {1.433}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\MSonehalfspacing

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}
\usepackage[withpage]{acronym}
\newcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill} 
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill} 


%Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%Mathe
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}

%Elektrische Zeichnungen
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

%Grafik
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
%Bildunterschrift
\usepackage[margin=2 cm,font=small,labelfont=bf,]
{caption}

% Listings
\usepackage{listings}

%Zähleranpassung
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{part}
\counterwithout{table}{part}
\counterwithout{equation}{part}

%Kopf-/Fußzeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[C]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\small \leftmark}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\authorOne}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
%%  Linien in Kopf- und Fußzeile
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
 }

\fancypagestyle{framepart}{
  \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[C]{}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\authorOne}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
 }

\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}


%Punkte im Inhaltsverzeichnis als Füllobjekte
\usepackage[]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}


%Formelverzeichnis:
\usepackage[version-1-compatibility]{siunitx}
\newcommand{\acrou}[1]{\acroextra{\makebox[18mm][l]{\si[per-mode=fraction,fraction=nice]{#1}}}}


%Überschriftformatierung
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\LARGE\bfseries\color{black}}{\thechapter\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesection\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesubsubsection\quad}{0pt}{}

%Abstände nach den Überschriften
\titlespacing{\chapter}         {   0em}        {   -8ex}   {   0ex}
\titlespacing{\section}         {   0em}        {   0ex}    {   -2ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}      {   0em}        {   0ex}    {   -2ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}   {   0em}        {   0ex}    {   -2ex}

%%Weiteres
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}

%PDF Einstellungen
\usepackage[%
    pdftitle={Info},
    pdfauthor={Info},
    pdfsubject={Info},
    pdfcreator={pdflatex, LaTeX with KOMA-Script},
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
    pdflang=de, 
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{papula,horowitz}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

  \bibitem{papula} Papula, Lothar: {\em Mathematik für Ingenieure und Naturwissenschaftler.} Band 3. 3.Aufl., München: Vieweg+Teubner Verlag, 2016

  \bibitem{horowitz} Horowitz, Paul \& Hill, Winfield: {\em The Art of Electronics.} 3.Aufl., Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2015

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately I don't know how to increase the horizontal space between the numerations and the info which comes afterwards. E.g. instead of (1)-Papula I would like to have (1)----Papula. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is my impression that you build the bibliography by hand correct? Please advise. Please also state which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I am building the bibliography by hand. I will supply more information tomorrow.

Comment: For many document classes, the width of the separation is set in the definition of `thebibliography`, as `\labelsep`.  Because the indentation of the items is recalculated based on the width of the label, `\labelsep` can't be reset separately, but will require a patch to `thebibliography`.  So that will require knowing the document class.

Comment: It would be great if you could complete the code snippets shown so far to a complete and compilable document that reproduces the screenshot (this is often called an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/, it should contain as little code as possible, but as much code as required to reproduce the relevant bits of output you get at the moment). At the very least we need to know which document class you use, but if you use additional bibliography/citation-related packages those could be relevant as well.

Comment: @moewe I added my complete preamble and the example.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but still something you should take a look at: I get several warnings from this document. Amongst them `Usage of package `fancyhdr' together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.` (don't use a KOMA-Script class and `famcyhdr`) `Package tocstyle Warning: THIS IS A DEPRECATED ALPHA VERSION! ... THE PACKAGE IS FROZEN WITH ALL IT'S BUGS! IT WILL BE REMOVED FROM KOMA-SCRIPT SOON!` (try to find a replacement for `tocstyle`) `Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \section detected.` (don't use `titlesec` and a KOMA-Script class together), ....

Comment: ... `Package tocstyle Warning: Usage of `tocstyle' with new `tocbasic' detected. This is not an error! You can do this.` (try dropping `tocstyle` see above). You may also want to double check if you really need all the packages you load. Usually it is better to load as few packages as possible.

Comment: Yes, I saw those warnings. I got this as a template from a colleague who wrote his thesis with it. I only slightly changed it and everything looks fine so far. It's only the spacing in the References that bothers me. But I already got rid of the tocstyle package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thebibliography` is a list pretty much like `enumerate` with some syntactic sugar on top. Hence, the space between the (citation) label and the bibliography item is controlled by `\labelsep` (the default value of `\labelsep` is `0.5em`). You could simply enlarge this value with `\setlength{\labelsep}{1em}`, but if you do that in the preamble this applies to all lists in your document.

I think it can be useful to redefine `thebibliography` so it gets a `\labelsep` of its own: `\biblabelsep`.

Essentially it is enough to define the new length `\biblabelsep` and to add `\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%` in the right place in `thebibliography`.
It would be possible (and shorter) to achieve the same with a patch, but it may be instructive to see how `thebibliography` is defined.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,pagesize,parskip,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength{\biblabelsep}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{2\labelsep}

\makeatletter
% copied from scrreprt.cls
% we just added the line
% \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \if@bib@break@
    \bib@beginhook
  \else
    \ifx\bibpreamble\relax\else\ifx\bibpreamble\@empty\else
        \setchapterpreamble{\bibpreamble}%
    \fi\fi
    \bib@heading
    \bib@beginhook
    \bib@before@hook
  \fi
  \renewcommand{\BreakBibliography}[1]{%
    \@bib@break
    \end{thebibliography}%
    \begingroup ##1\endgroup
    \begin{thebibliography}{#1}
  }%
  \list{%
    \@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
  }{%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
    \settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \@openbib@code
    \if@bib@break@
      \edef\@tempa{%
        \noexpand\usecounter{enumiv}%
        \noexpand\setcounter{enumiv}{\the\c@enumiv}%
      }\@tempa
      \no@bib@break
    \else
      \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \fi
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty
    \renewcommand*\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
  }%
  \sloppy\clubpenalty4000 \widowpenalty4000
  \sfcode`\.=\@m
}{%
  \if@bib@break@
    \def\@noitemerr{%
      \@latex@warning{%
        \string\BreakBibliography\space at begin of `thebibliography'
        environment\MessageBreak
        or following \string\BreakBibliography}%
    }%
  \else
    \def\@noitemerr{%
      \@latex@warning{%
        Empty `thebibliography' environment or
        \string\BreakBibliography\MessageBreak
        before end of `thebibliography' environment}%
    }%
  \fi
  \endlist
  \if@bib@break@
  \else
    \bib@after@hook
    \let\bib@before@hook\@empty
    \let\bib@after@hook\@empty
  \fi
  \bib@endhook
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{papula,horowitz}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

  \bibitem{papula} Papula, Lothar:
  {\em Mathematik für Ingenieure und Naturwissenschaftler.} Band 3.
  3.~Aufl., München: Vieweg+Teubner Verlag, 2016

  \bibitem{horowitz} Horowitz, Paul \& Hill, Winfield: {\em The Art of Electronics.}
  3.~Aufl., Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2015

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with double the normal labelsep.]

You can modify the horizontal space with

```
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{2\labelsep}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. That is very kind of you and much appreciated.